# Proving that a function is continuous on an interval

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

It has been a while since I have taken an analysis course and I have a question regarding continuity at a point. I am working on the following question.

> Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $$
> f(x) = \left\{
>         \begin{array}{ll}
>             x+1 & \quad x \geq 0 \\
>             x-1 & \quad x < 0
>         \end{array}
>     \right.
> $$
>   Prove that $f$ is continuous at $c$ when $c \neq 0$.

The definition of continuity at a point $c$ is defined as:

$\forall \epsilon >0 \exists \delta >0 \forall x \in \mathbb{R} (|x-c|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon)$.

**proof attempt:**

Consider two cases: (1) $c<0$, (2) $c>0$.

(1) If $c<0$, then we are looking at all $x<0$. $|f(x)-f(c)|=|x-1-f(c)|$ and we want this to be less than $\epsilon$. However, this is where I am getting stuck and I am not sure how to continue. I feel as though case (2) will be very similar.

Any insight/hints in the right direction are appreciated, please no full solution though, I would like to understand this fully myself. Thank you.

Comment: You don't use $\delta$ in your attempt? Fix $\epsilon$, then choose $\delta$ such that for $x$ such that $|x-c|<\delta$, $f(x)$ will be sufficiently close to $f(c)$ (ie $x-1$ will be sufficiently close to $c-1$, ie $|x-c|<\epsilon$). Any idea what $\delta$ would suffice? :)

Comment: Yes. Well, except if $c$ is too close from $0$, because then $f(x)$ and $f(c)$ could have different signs. You can probably use a $\delta = \min(\epsilon, c)/2$ then (to check).

Comment: I mean if you aren't considering $c\neq 0$, you don't really need epsilon-delta arguments right?

Comment: @Nameless If you know that polynomial are continuous, no. Based on his attempt, I guess the OP wants to prove it from scratch.

Comment: @Joseph Let's take a simple case: $f(x)=r$ over $\mathbb{R}$. What $\delta$ would you choose to prove continuity at a given $c$?

Comment: Exactly. So in the example your deleted ($r$ over $\mathbb{R}^-$ and $s$ over $\mathbb{R}^{*+}$), the only concern is to make sure $x$ and $c$ have the same sign. So you just have to find a $\delta$ which will ensure that.

Comment: @anderstood OK, that makes much more sense. I was getting stuck at the point where $x$ and $c$ had different signs. Can we choose $\delta$ to be an inequality or does it also have to be an exact value? For the example that I deleted, I attempted to use $\delta<|a|$ which seemed to work fine.

Comment: You need to choose one (but there is an infinity of possibilities). For example $\delta = \min(c,\epsilon)/2$, or $\min(c,\epsilon)/10$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

**For case 1 ($c<0$):**

Let $\varepsilon  > 0$.
Choose $\delta  = \min \left\{ { - \frac{c}{2},\frac{\varepsilon }{2}} \right\}$

Let there be $x \in \Re$ such that $\left| {x - c} \right| < \delta $.

Notice that $$\left| {x - c} \right| <  - \frac{c}{2}$$
hence
$$\frac{c}{2} < x - c <  - \frac{c}{2}$$
therefore
$$x < \frac{c}{2} < 0$$
Now look at $$\left| {f\left( x \right) - f\left( c \right)} \right| = ...$$

Can you continue from here?